# Will APCu work on Apache 2.4 (Win64) with PHP7 installed as Apache module?

Tags: php, apache, apcu

I have a single, simple **Apache/2.4.46** server running on **Windows 64-bit**, paired with **PHP/7.4.15**.

PHP is installed as an Apache module *(LoadModule php7_module ".../php7apache2_4.dll").*

My question is: **will APCu be functional in such setup?**

In other words:

1. Will all PHP scripts executed in parallel (= handling simultaneous HTTP requests)
   "see" the same, single cache?
2. And will this cache be kept alive between subsequent HTTP requests?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it works fine - both conditions are met.